# Uncaught Error: Could not find module simple-auth-devise/configuration

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am trying to migrate from windows to ubuntu. I have ember app that runs find on windows but same project on ubuntu throws `error Uncaught Error: Could not find module simple-auth-devise/configuration`

steps i followed

1. git clone
2. npm install && bower install
3. ember serve

on widows
app\node_modules\ember-cli-simple-auth-devise\app\initializers

```
import initializer from 'simple-auth-devise/initializer';
export default initializer;
```

on ubuntu

```
import Configuration from 'simple-auth-devise/configuration';
import Authenticator from 'simple-auth-devise/authenticators/devise';
import Authorizer from 'simple-auth-devise/authorizers/devise';
import ENV from '../config/environment';

export default {
  name:       'simple-auth-devise',
  before:     'simple-auth',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    Configuration.load(container, ENV['simple-auth-devise'] || {});
    container.register('simple-auth-authorizer:devise', Authorizer);
    container.register('simple-auth-authenticator:devise', Authenticator);
  }
};
```

index.html

```
<script>
      window.EventorENV = {{ENV}};
      window.EmberENV = window.EventorENV.EmberENV;
      window.ENV = window.ENV || {};
      window.ENV['simple-auth'] = {
        authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise'
      }
    </script>
    <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/eventor.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.Eventor = require('eventor/app')['default'].create(EventorENV.APP);
    </script>
```

Comment: did you run the generator for the Ember CLI Simple Auth Addon (`ember g ember-cli-simple-auth-devise`, `ember g ember-cli-simple-auth`)?

Comment: ember g ember-cli-simple-auth updated version 0.6.7 and it work for me now thanks